# Where to save credit card detail? is it good to store in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, credit-card

I have  created the e-commerce site where user can buy product by credit card.

I don't want to ask client credit card detail again, if once he purchased the product.Next time it should be automatically comes.

Is it ok to store credit card detail in database with some algorithm or is there any third party system ?

Please help me

Comment: I don't think your users would be too happy about you saving their credit card numbers in your database.

Comment: There are professional payment providers which you could use in your shop

Comment: DON'T DO THAT, let users enter their credit card numbers every time they purchase, it's not safe

Comment: There are multiple duplicates to this question

Comment: You don't want this liability. Multiple third party providers will do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

You should never store credit card in your database as they are vulnerable to misuse. Instead go for third party system which offer you to store this secure information for eg. [ACH](http://www.achdirect.com/paymentsgateway/), they provide you to store the information and return you the client id which you can use for next time to process payment.